# Using Alt keys for switching workplaces doens't take priority over context menus in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys, ccsm

Maybe I'm missing a configuration somewhere, but setting the same <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> keyboard shortcut for switching workplace left doesn't function in the same way as it did in my 12.04 setup.  It used to be the case that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> in 12.04 would supercede any other keyboard shortcuts, specifically the context menu. Since pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> blocks the switching workplace shortcut, I can no longer use it to switch workplaces if the active window already has a shortcut for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> (firefox, XChat, etc).

How do I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> as my window switching shortcut without getting blocked by the window context menu shortcut?